# List with in List using Lambda

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, lambda

I have two table That i want to combine to generate a report

[image: User List]

[image: Transaction]

I use this code to join the table

```
db.tblProcessorLists.GroupJoin(
                 db.tbltransactions,
                 a => a.UserID,
                 b => b.UserID,
                 (x, y) => new
                 {
                     Processor = x,
                     Data = y.ToList()
                 }
         )
         .Select(a => new Report
         {
             Processor = a.Processor,
             TotalTrans = a.Data
         }).ToList();
```

and this the output

[image]

I want to insert the data in my report class.

[image]

is this possible and how?

EDIT
I already tried this but its not working

```
db.tblProcessorLists.GroupJoin(
                 db.tbltransactions,
                 a => a.UserID,
                 b => b.UserID,
                 (x, y) => new
                 {
                     Processor = x,
                     Data = y.ToList()
                 }
         )
         .Select(a => new Report
         {
             Processor = a.Processor,
             SummaryTransaction = a.Data.Select(x=>new Summaryreport{ month=x.month, year=x.year, total=x.totaltransaction})
         }).ToList();
```

Comment: @TDK I already add what i try

Comment: You may get more answers tagging your question with C# and LINQ rather than WPF (I don't see any WPF in your question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you didn't specify, I think what you want is to sum all Data of one month. So instead of:

```
Processor Month   Value
    1    2018-1     2
    1    2018-1     3  => sum all 2018-1 values of processor 1: 2+3=5
    1    2018-2     4
    1    2018-2     5  => sum all 2018-2 values of processor 1: 4+5=9
    2    2018-1     1
    2    2018-1     2  => sum all 2018-1 values of processor 2: 1+2=3
```

All you have to do is change the ResultSelector in your GroupJoin, such that it groups all data into groups with same [year, month]. The result is [year, month, sum] of all values with this year and month]

See one of the overloads of [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3__)

```
var result = db.tblProcessorLists.GroupJoin(  // GroupJoin processors and transactions
    db.tbltransactions,
    processor => processor.UserID,       // from every processor take the UserId
    transaction => transaction.UserID,   // from every transaction take the UserId

    // ResultSelector: use eacht processor with its zero or more matching transactions
    // to make one new object
    (processor, transactionsOfThisProcessor) => new
    {
        Processor = processor,

        // group all transactionsOfThisProcessor into groups with same [year, month]
        // and sum the values of all transactions in each group
        TransactionTotals = transactionsOfThisProcessor
            .GroupBy(transaction => new 
            {
                Year = transaction.Year,       // KeySelector: make groups with 
                Month = transaction.Month      // same [year, month]
            },

            // element selector: Transaction.Value
            transaction => transaction.Value,

            // ResultSelector: key = [year, month],
            // elements are all values of this [year, month] group
            // sum all values
            (key, valuesWithThisYearMonth) => new
            {
                Year = key.Year,
                Month = key.Month,
                Total = valuesWithThisYearMonth.Sum(),
            }),
    });
```